# Is it possible to automate said named range?

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas

### INPUTS

```
Type   | Quantity | Serial # |

Apple  | 2        | ABC,DEF

Orange | 3        | GHI,JKL,MNO
```

---

### **Desired Output**

```
Apple  | ABC

Apple  | DEF

Orange | GHI

Orange | JKL

Orange | LMN
```

Comment: It's possible. In fact, there was a question just like this not so long ago and I submitted an answer. You may like to search among my answers for the past month or 6 weeks. As an alternative, please post the code you wrote yourself and we'll help you fix it if you point us at the hurdle it put up for you.

Comment: =transpose(split(A1, ",",1,1)) Thanks I will search your old posts but the issue with my formula is that mine is way too static and repetitive. Id have to enter it a few more times since it isn't a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A&"♦"&SPLIT(C2:C, ",")), "♦"), 
 "where not Col2 matches '\s+?|^$'", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Perfect. Apologies for the late reply, but thanks again! You are a God send